# Como adicionar espaços antes de um número?

Tags: vba, loop

Estou tentando adicionar espaços antes de números.
O primeiro código deu certo, mas queria fazer em forma de *loop*.

```
Sub numeros()

numero = Range("A2").Value
n = 3
    If Len(Range("A" & n).Value) = 3 Then
        numero = Range("A" & n).Value
    ElseIf Len(Range("A" & n).Value) = 2 Then
        numero = " " & Range("A" & n).Value
    ElseIf Len(Range("A" & n).Value) = 1 Then
        numero = "  " & Range("A" & n).Value
    End If
        Range("B" & n).Value = "|" & numero & "|"
End Sub
```

O mais perto que cheguei foi o *loop* abaixo. Porém ele entra em *loop* infinito, pois o VBA não entende que a quantidade de caracteres passou de 3.

```
Sub numeros2()

n = 1
numero = 1
espaço = 0
    Do Until Len(numero) = 3
        numero = Space(espaço) & numero
        espaço = espaço + 1
    Loop
    Range("B" & n).Value = "|" & numero & "|"
End Sub
```

[image: Segue exemplo do resultado pretendido com o loop]

Comment: Daniel, desculpe a pergunta que provavelmente não será válida, mas você pode formatar as células para ficar alinhadas à direita, seria o caso?

Answer (score 2):

Agradeço por ter dado uma atenção ao código.

Evert: Tentei fazer isso mas mesmo assim não deu certo.

Leandro: Realmente os 3 If's são mais simples e não tem necessidade de mudar. Mas eu queria estudar as formas de se fazer loop.

Felizmente, hoje resolvi pensar diferente e fiz o seguinte código que deu certo.

```
Sub numeros1()
Dim numero As String
n = 1
numero = Range("A1").Value
n2 = 0

Do Until Len(numero) > 3
    numero = Space(n2) & numero
    n2 = n2 + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Também funciona se trocar mudar do `Do Until Len(numero) > 3` para `Do While Len(numero) > 3`. Estranho que ser for `Do Until Len(numero) = 3` não da certo...

Abraços!

Answer (score 0):

Oi, então, se for somente pra até 3 caracteres, eu acho muito mais simples escrever 3 if's assim:

```
Sub numeros2()

    Dim numero

    Rng = Columns(1).End(xlDown).Row

    For i = 1 To Rng

        numero = Cells(i, 1)

        If Len(numero) = 1 Then

            Range("B" & i) = "|  " & numero & "|"

        ElseIf Len(numero) = 2 Then

            Range("B" & i) = "| " & numero & "|"

        ElseIf Len(numero) = 3 Then

            Range("B" & i) = "|" & numero & "|"

        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```

Agora se você quiser utilizar o `Do Until` pra uma possível expansão no numero de caracteres eu posso fazer também.